# How to iterate through date and time stamps in a CSV and seperate the data based on the day of the year

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

```
Date     time   kWh
1/1/2016 00:00  34.56
1/1/2016 00:15  34.56
1/1/2016 00:30  34.56
1/1/2016 00:45  34.56
1/1/2016 01:00  34.56
1/1/2016 01:15  34.56
1/1/2016 01:30  34.128
1/1/2016 01:45  34.992
1/1/2016 02:00  34.128
1/1/2016 02:15  34.56
1/1/2016 02:30  34.128
1/1/2016 02:45  34.992
```

I have got electricity consumption every 15 minutes over entire year 2016 in a CSV file. I want to calculate total consumption based on day of the week i.e total electricity consumption on Mondays, Tuesdays, etc in 2016.

I tried making a list() of the data and assuming first day as Friday, sliced the list based on the position of the data but it turns out that the data is not consistent and has some missing numbers.

Is there a way to assign a weekday to each data point which will eliminate the problem of missing data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you parse the dates and create `datetime` objects from them, you can find out what the weekday is. Your date format is non-standard, so you can't use `strptime()` to parse it, but you can use a regex:

```
import re
import datetime

date = '1/1/2016 00:00'
m = re.search('^(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', date)
d = datetime.datetime(day=int(m.group(1)), month=int(m.group(2)), year=int(m.group(3)))
print d.weekday() # prints 4 = Friday
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin, this worked after making a small change as follows: `day=int(m.group(2)), month=int(m.group(1))`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up on the datetime module.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

In particular I believe the documentation on date.weekday() solves the problem for you:
date.weekday()
Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. For example, date(2002, 12, 4).weekday() == 2, a Wednesday. See also isoweekday().